# How to stack data in plot without breaking normalization

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I need to work with huge csv files looking something like this

```
x       y1      y2      y3      y4      y5      y6      y7      y8      y9
5.01    0.11    0.12    0.12    0.12    0.12    0.12    0.11    0.12    0.11
5.04    0.11    0.12    0.12    0.12    0.12    0.12    0.11    0.11    0.11
5.07    0.11    0.12    0.11    0.12    0.12    0.12    0.11    0.12    0.11
5.09    0.11    0.12    0.12    0.12    0.12    0.12    0.11    0.11    0.10
...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
47.88   1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00
47.90   0.91    0.99    0.88    0.96    0.94    0.98    0.86    0.86    0.85
47.93   0.70    0.81    0.63    0.76    0.73    0.78    0.61    0.61    0.59
47.95   0.46    0.55    0.41    0.51    0.47    0.53    0.40    0.39    0.38
```

I need to grab the data and plot it and to make it easier to compare.

I've tried to stack them on top of each other

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', index_col=0)
plt.figure(); df.plot(stacked=True); plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

And I get the following,

[Stacked data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oANzg.png)

where the normalization of the data is messed up

I've tried to use the subplot keyword

```
plt.figure(); df.plot(subplots=True); plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

In that case, I get this

[Plot using subplot keyword](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiyxV.png)

The sharing of the x-axis is perfect and now I don't have the normalization of the data messed up. However, I have these frames and I'm not able to remove them, also I wanted a single legend with all the entries like in the figure above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prepared four data frames for simple line graphs and used them as data frames. By using fig, we can get the legend and handle from each axis and add them to the list. Finally, we set the labels and handles retrieved by `fig.legend()`.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

y1 = np.linspace(0,1,50).cumsum()
y2 = np.linspace(0,1,50).cumsum() + 0.01
y3 = np.linspace(0,1,50).cumsum() + 0.02
y4 = np.linspace(0,1,50).cumsum() + 0.03

df = pd.DataFrame({'y1':y1, 'y2':y2, 'y3':y3, 'y4':y4})

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot(subplots=True, legend=False, ax=ax)

lines = []
labels = []

for ax in fig.axes:
    axLine, axLabel = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
    lines.extend(axLine)
    labels.extend(axLabel)
    
fig.legend(lines, labels, loc='center', bbox_to_anchor=(1.0,0.5))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The pandas plot is easy to visualize, but if you want to customize it a bit, you will need to know matplotlib. If my answer was helpful to you, please accept it as the correct answer with a check mark.

Comment: Thank you for the answer the problem with this is that I need to input the number of columns by hand. While in the example I gave, I have only 9 samples most times the data I analyze have much more, or less and I wanted to write something that can handle that alone

Comment: The code you answer will be automatically looped through without recognizing the number of columns. Where is the manual input of the number of columns you are referring to?

Comment: Here

`y1 = np.linspace(0,1,50).cumsum()
y2 = np.linspace(0,1,50).cumsum() + 0.01
y3 = np.linspace(0,1,50).cumsum() + 0.02
y4 = np.linspace(0,1,50).cumsum() + 0.03

df = pd.DataFrame({'y1':y1, 'y2':y2, 'y3':y3, 'y4':y4})`

Comment: It's just sample data, so replace it with your own data.